# Is there anything the moderators could do to stop the offensive edits from anonymous users?

Tags: support, editing, spam

Anonymous users are adding abusive edits to two of my questions regularly with the f word,it is just annoying, is there something the moderators could do about this issue?

Comment: The solution is to reject them as spam. Closely related https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1358/277

Comment: @Pandya Suggested edits cannot be _flagged_.

Comment: @user6655984 oh. I mean reject them as spam.

Comment: This is happening frequently in my case too.